# HTTPS and Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: redirects, https

A client has a Wordpress website with an SSL certificate. 
Through .htacces it redirects from non-www to www.

If you access the web through:

- https://www.example.com > OK (default)
- http://www.example.com > redirects to https://www.example.com
- http://example.com > redirects to https://www.example.com
- https://example.com > Error 102 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Any idea why it fails for the last one?
It seems that SSL is working, but just for `www.example.com`

*Edit to add more information as asked:*

The error is neither browser-specific (tried it with different browsers and OS) nor location-specific as is happening at different locations. Website is up and redirection from http://example.com to https://www.example.com works fine.

Comment: Have you looked at this article?  What solutions have you tried?  Is it browser specific or location specific?  It would help to know what other things you have tried.  https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/hosting/technical-matters/err-connection-refused/

Comment: HTTP 1.1 uses host headers to separate/identify when multiple hostnames are used on the same IP address.  Is it possible that your webserver needs you to add the `https://example.com` in its HTTP configuration?

Comment: What server are you using?  (Apache, Nginx, IIS, something else?)   How are the virtual hosts configured?   (Is there a virtual host configured for `example.com` on port 443)?      What are the host names for the SSL certificate?   (It sounds like it covers `www.example.com` but it might not have an alternative name for `example.com`)?

Comment: I have no idea, I only have access to FTP and DB but not to the control panel/server. I've told the client to open a ticket with their hosting provider as it seems the problem is on their side.